# Проектирование моделей DDD

Tags: asp.net, архитектура, ddd

Всем доброго дня! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с DDD. Допустим, есть у меня сущность RegCard, которая является корнем агрегата, у нее есть поле Source (ссылка на сущность Источник). Source содержит код и имя, и является что то типа справочника (хранится в бд). В данном проекте с Source мы можем только получить данные. Чем является Source? Entity внутри агрегата RegCard, отдельный агрегат или же ValueObject?

Answer (score 2):

`DDD` - про проектирование ориентированное (`driven`) на домен, соответственно это зависит только от домена и того как вы это спроектируете (единственно правильного решения нет), основываясь на различиях `Entity`, `Value Object` (это можно нагуглить, или почитать в книгах), вы можете и принять решение. Вполне можно спроектировать один домен в котором у вас `Source` будет `Entity`, а в другом - `Value Object` (В одном домене `Book` это просто `Value Object`, который говорит, что у пользователя есть такая книга, и нам все равно что на её номер, нам достаточно названия, а в другом мы трекаем каждую книгу отдельно, даже если у них одинаковое название, нам важда каждая сущность).

Например, если рассматривать ваш пример, то `Source` это вполне нормальная `Entity`, т.к. у вас есть код (который может выступать id/identity), у вас может быть четкий жизненный цикл этой сущности и т.д. Наример, вы захотите поменять имя у этого `Source`, но код останется прежним. Т.е. это является полноценной `Entity`, которым манипулирует домен.

Но вполне можно посмотреть на это с другой стороны и сделать `Value Object`. Рассматривая это как immutable `Value Object`. Т.к. у вас в описании нет никак бизнес операций, которые вы выполняете над вашим агрегатом, то, пока, такой подход выглядит проще. Этот `Value Object` будет составной частью вашеко агрегата, т.е. он будет обычным аттрибутом (характеристикой) вашего агрегата, которая не будет рассматриваться отдельно. Наример, `RegCard` (регистрационная карта) была выдана `Source` (некий орган), для вас важно сохранить эту информацию, но ваш домен не занимается полным управлением каждого отдельного органа (а то где, это будет храниться для модели не важно, это уже детали реализации вашего хранилища).

Единстенное если у вас в `RegCard` хранится ссылка на объект `Source`, то это точно не отдельный агрегат, т.к. прямые (ссылочные) связи меджу агрегатами не является хорошим подходом, а должны быть связи между ними быть только по ID. Агрегат определяет границу соблюдения инваниантов и границу транзакций (где-то это называли так "transaction boundaries"), т.к. у вас репозитории опирируют агрегатами (read/save) и только ими, если будет сущиствовать ссылка на другой агрегат, то при сохранение одного вы можете обновить другой, а уже получается "спрятанная"/неявная бизнес логика (зависимость), которая должна быть описана явно со стороны бизнеса/домена.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Если использовать Source как Value Object, правильно ли хранить в RegCard (в бд) только SourceId или же нам обязательно сохранить весь Source? И ещё, ко всем сущностям нужно обращаться через агрегатную сущность. Как я правильно могу получить список всех Source, например, чтоб передать на фронт для выбора из списка? Могу я в репозитории RegCard получать список всех Source, независимо от RegCard?